# Customizing hvplot box

Tags: python, holoviews, hvplot

I am trying to get deep into `hvplot` to see if I can find a good alternative to `plotly`, but I am baffled by the documentation.

I am trying to plot boxplots with jittered points, and a basic tutorial can be found [here](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/reference/pandas/box.html).

The part of the example I am trying to customize is this:

```
import hvplot.pandas
from bokeh.sampledata.sprint import sprint as df
boxplot = df.hvplot.box(y='Time', by='Medal', height=400, width=400, legend=False)
boxplot
```

However, I want to style my plot, for example by removing the borders of each box, changing opacity, box width, and so on.

I tried to search that in the hvplot page, but the documentation seem to be limited to some basic examples and not much more.

On stackoverflow I managed to find some pointers to [how to style plots](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Styling_Plots.html) but I tried and failed to find out how to do the above mentioned things.

Is there a more detailed documentation somewhere or do I just need to get deeper into holoviews?

Answer (score 2):

Update:

I found [in the customization guide of HvPlot](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Customization.html) that one can call `hvplot.help('box')`. That contains all the possibile options. The fact that `box_color` doesn't work still eludes me (`box_fill_color` works) but at least that's a more detailed explanation of how it works.
Leaving it here just in case someone else needs it.